# Dock is semi-functional after Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, dock

So I updated to Mountain Lion recently, and as far as I can tell everything has been great. Except that Dock doesn’t really function as it is supposed to. It shows up, but when I launch an application from it, it does not recognize that the application is running. The only app that it recognizes as open is Finder. 

Also (and I’m assuming that this is coming from the same problem), when I do `⌘ + tab` it only shows Finder as an open application (like the Dock).

Is there a way that I can maybe restart the dock?

Thanks, Asher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than a reboot, you can try the following in *Terminal.app*

> `killall Dock`

Answer (score 0):

Start Activity monitor, select Dock, in the upper left corner is a red symbol that looks like a stop sign and is labeled quit process click this and a window will come up with the options to force quit, cancel or quit. I use quit (I have not had to use force quit) if it does not restart the dock just go to the dashboard and it will restart the dock.